# What is the Gol D. Roger's ability 'To hear the voice of all Things' that Rayleigh is talking about?

Tags: one-piece

In Chapter 507, Rayleigh was talking about the power 'To hear the voice of all things' that Gold D. Roger has. It seems to explain how he was able to write in the ancient language on the Sky Island's Poneglyph. What is that phenomenon?

[image]

Comment: Well, the wiki (http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gol_D._Roger) says that, "{a}ccording to Rayleigh, Roger could interpret the Poneglyphs because he had the ability to "hear the voice of all things". He was also one of two known humans in the series who possessed the ability to hear Sea Kings speaking, the other being Luffy." Seeing as they are listed together they might be linked and be something along the lines of being able to understand all languages, but I do not recall if Luffy ever tried to read a Poneglyph so they might be more disconnected than what my train of thought is.

Answer (score 2):

As we have seen Luffy being considered as successor of Pirate King. One of the most important fact that support it is the voice of all things. Though in case of Luffy this ability is somewhat incomparable with Gold D. Roger, it allows Luffy mainly to interact with ancient beings. 
The instances where Luffy was able to used this power was:

1. Understanding Ryuuji(Green millennial dragon from east blue)
2. Understanding the sea kings from fishman island
3. Hearing from Zunisha in Zoe island

Although Roger was able to interact with poneglyph Luffy has not shown this power so far.

**From above instances, this power is somewhat like voice of heart and seems to be used by fated ones**.

Though  Momonosuke talked with Zunisha it is only limited to it and not more.

So, sit back and wait for history of world to unfold then only we will be able to know what exactly it is. **As of now it is highly related to successor of the kingdom of D. (who is fated of course) for controlling the treasures and weapons of the kingdom of D**.

Comment: The question isn't really about luffy's extent of this power. He's just asking about what exactly the power is

Answer (score 1):

The voice of all things seems to be a special power which hasnt really been explored a lot by oda sensei yet . One major encounter with it although has been in the case of momonosuke who could hear and command zunisha to do something . Luffy has shown traits . This power apparently also allows people to decipher poneglyphs. Taken from the one piece wikia :

> This power grants the user the ability to understand and gain information through creatures and inanimate objects who do not speak the same language.So far, this seems to be an ability gained from birth.
>
> Some people use this ability to read the Poneglyphs.
>
> The Three-Eye Tribe is rumored to have access to this ability through utilizing the power of their third eye.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only Roger who has this ability, but also [Momonosuke](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kozuki_Momonosuke#Zunisha) and Luffy in weaker form (he could not answer to Zunisha). There is little information about it but, since Momonosuke has this ability, it is unlikely that it has something to do with "D". It may even be nothing more than an extremely rare form of, or just extraordinary strong Haki.